# Automatically assign entities created by workflows to fields

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

We've got a [workflow](http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/processes/workflows/) which creates 3 entities:

- `SourceAssessment`
- `SourceLegal`
- `SourcePartnershipValidation`

each entity have got 1 lookup field under [Business Process Flow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531135.aspx):

[image]

And the same workflow is configured to update the above 3 lookup fields with newly created entities:

[image]

[image]
However, the creation part seems to be working fine but not the assigning part.

Have tried implementing the *Automatic Record Creation and Update Rules* from [Service Management & Business Management Settings](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/set-up-rules-to-automatically-create-or-update-records-in-dynamics-365.aspx)

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of "Set Properties" page?

Comment: @dynamicallycrm [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE23l.png). I do not have privileges to add extra images in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to assign the 'Source Legal' record value to the Project record. For that, You have to map the created records from 'Local Values' group in 'Look for' dropdown from 'Set Properties' window.

[image]

See the slug (yellow placeholder text) for difference. This will work.

[image]